# Microsoft Graph get Presence instead of users

Tags: javascript, authentication, microsoft-graph-api

I want to get Presence from Microsoft graph and I found the code from the github https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-nodejs-console. I want to try to change it from users into me/presence but there is an error 403 but I already give permission from my delegated and also application permission.

I change

```
const apiConfig = {
    //uri: process.env.GRAPH_ENDPOINT + 'v1.0/users', // e.g. 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users'
    // uri: process.env.GRAPH_ENDPOINT + 'v1.0/me/presence',
    uri: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/a355ae26-f7e4-4ff8-ab3c-cb1c24dc2823/presence',
}
```

and

```
 case 'getPresence':

        try{
            const authResponse = await auth.getToken(auth.tokenRequest);
            const users = await fetch.callApi(auth.apiConfig.uri, authResponse.accessToken);
            console.log(users);
        } catch (error){
            console.log(error);
        }
        break;
```

Comment: How do you authenticate? With client id and client secret?

Comment: yes, I put my client id, client secret, and tenant id in the .env file.

Comment: When using client secret, you cannot call /me endpoint, because you are not signed on behalf any user. So, only way to get your presence is /users/{your-id}/presence

Comment: I tried just now, I changed the uri but there is still error with 403 but I already checked all the permission.

Comment: Please check the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http): Get presence endpoint doesn't support application permissions, so, you will need to change the authentication to authenticate on behalf of user

Comment: Can the user sign in only once in my application and in the future I do not need to ask the user to sign in and give their permission? do you think it is possible? This is my first time working with API, maybe you have a suggestion is there any YouTube channel or open source code project that it can help me?